# Projectile Motion Ball

Tags: discrete-mathematics, physics, mathematical-physics

I'm stuck on a problem:

**Suppose a person standing on the top of a building of $160$ft high throws a ball directly upward with initial speed of $48$ ft/sec. When does the ball hit the ground, and how long did the ball travel during its flight?**

So I found the position function is $-16t^2+48t+160$. The time I found is $5$ seconds for it to hit the ground.

**how do i find the distance it traveled over its flight?**

UPDATE: With the help of the two people in the comments:

So the vertex is $t=-b/2a$, so it's $\frac{-48}{-32}$ so it is $t=1.5$? and then at $t=1.5,$ $p(t)$ is $196$. So it's $196+196-160$ so it's $232$!

Comment: Hm, well given that function you only need to find the vertex of the graph. The distance traveled will be equal to it's maximum height plus the maximum height minus 160 ft. Right? Maybe I'm not understanding the question. You may even have better luck posting this over on the physics stack-exchange.

Comment: So the vertex is t=-b/2a, so it's -(48)/(-32) so it is t=1.5? and then at t=1.5 p(t) is 196. So it's 196+196-160 so its 232? I think that's right!

Comment: You will need to find the objects starting position, highest point, and final position.  And the ball will trace all of the points in between.

Comment: @taffies1 Right, you've got it.

Comment: @Dodsy, how can I make your answer the one with a green arrow. Meaning how can I make you're answer display as correct?

Comment: @Taffies1  You should post that work as an update to the original post, rather than as a comment.

Comment: @Taffies1 Because it is just a comment, not a full answer.